# gitlab registry installed with helm using wildcard cert returns x509

Tags: gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine

On GKE, I install gitlab ( 13.7.1-ee ) using helm chart.
And I use gitlab's wildcard certificate(https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html)

I also want to use gitlab container registry, so in values.yaml, I set

```
registry:
  enabled: true    
  certificate:
    secret: gitlab-registry-secret 
    key: registry-auth.crt
```

gitlab-registry-secret was created automatically so I thought I could use it.

install itself looks working correctly.

Then, following gitlab webpage's guide,

> $ docker login registry.[my-gitlab-domain]
> and it asked user & password; I use `root` and gitlab-initial-root-password.

but it returned

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

In GKE log, gitlab-registry showed waring

```
WARNING: ca-certificates.crt does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
```

---

I cannot find my mistakes.
I have no idea whether it's because of wildcard-cert or my configuration, or anything else.

I'm waiting someone's kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't configure your container Registry under an existing GitLab domain, you can't use the GitLab TLS certificate.

So when the Registry is configured to use its own domain, you need a TLS certificate for that specific domain (in your case, registry.[your-gitlab-domain]).